# <button> text align on top or bottom without css

Tags: html, button, ckeditor

Is it possible to align button's text (html) to top/bottom without using css or padding?
I am making a custom plugin in ckeditor and I would like the user to be able to align the text from a dialogue. That is the main reason I want to avoid CSS.

Comment: What is the rationale behind not using CSS?

Comment: So you want to say that you want to design something but don't want to use CSS?

Comment: I believe there was a valign property in the html spec at some point... I'm 90% sure that didn't make it to html5

Comment: Can you create a fiddle link so we can see?

Comment: It is for CKEditor. I want the user to align the text from a dialogue. That is the main reason. for left and right I can use text-align= ""; but it doesn't apply for top/bottom

Comment: @Dead Man, here is a fiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/vYTck/3/
I want to achieve this without padding/css

Answer (score -1):

I made the following changes in your fiddle and the text is aligned to centre

```
<button bean="a" property="a" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; padding-top: 8px; tabindex: ">1234567890<br />
```

1234567890

Comment: I am trying to accomplish that without padding. I tried with valign but looks to be not supported anymore. Maybe there is no way....

Comment: You used a wrong command...its `vertical-align:centre` updated your fiddle..hav a look http://jsfiddle.net/vYTck/6/

Comment: I want to align that to the top or bottom, not to center.